# Barra de atendimento no rodapé da página

Tags: html, css, rolamento

Como posso criar ou personalizar uma barra como a [deste site](http://www.sitegerenciavel.com.br/) que fica no rodapé com diversas opções de atendimento:

> [image: snapshot do site]

Esta barra azul clara com as opções de atendimento no rodapé.

Comment: Ao abrir a página, use o botão direito, e a opção "exibir código fonte", tem tudo lá. (dependendo do navegador, esta opção pode estar em algum sub-item do menu principal do navegador, mas em geral é uma opção parecida com essa)

Comment: Sendo ainda que quando tu põe o mouse em cima desloca 1px o texto.. Isso me dá uma agonia que você não imagina. Se for fazer igual corrige por favor.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal então aí tá bem melhor que aqui. Parece uma gelatina quando dou mouseover, tem coisa que anda 2px, tem coisa que anda 1, dependendo do lugar.

Comment: @PauloNunes Ah, mais uma idéia, use CSS em vez de `table`, como foi usado no tal site.

Answer (score 2):

Segue receita pronta (não otimizada para *browsers* mais velhos):

```css
html,body {
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%
}

#pagina {
  padding-bottom:60px;
}

#barra {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#079;
}

#promo, .botao {
  font: normal 30px/58px Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; 
}

#promo {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:60px;
  border-right:1px solid #068;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align:right;
  color: #fff;
}

.botao {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:58px;
  height:60px;
  border-left:1px solid #09B;
  border-right:1px solid #068;
  text-align:center;
}

.botao:hover {background-color:#ccc}
```

```html
<div id="pagina">
  Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
</div>
<div id="barra">
  <div id="promo">Batatinhas!</div>
  <a class="botao">1</a>
  <a class="botao">2</a>
  <a class="botao">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [:D](http://pt.lipsum.com/feed/html) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ipsum velit, auctor et sapien quis, fermentum consequat tellus. Sed aliquam non quam bibendum mollis. Donec accumsan ornare augue, nec iaculis eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur vel leo eros. Donec eget vehicula nunc, id eleifend neque. Cras fringilla porta sapien in commodo. Vestibulum placerat nibh massa, et varius lacus volutpat vel. Vestibulum dictum aliquam vestibulum. Morbi lobortis tincidunt interdum. Cras ornare ut tellus at dignissim.